# \network adapter(*)\bytes total/sec vs. task manager/performance -powershell

Tags: powershell

On Windows 10, in task manager/performance it gives the values for 'Receive' and 'Send' for network adapters. I got curious as to how MS does this so I thought of performance counters in powershell. So I cobbled together a quick bit of code to experiment with, put it in a background job, this:

```
$Computer = hostname;
$sndrecsum = {((get-counter -Counter '\network adapter(*)\Bytes Received/sec' -MaxSamples 30).CounterSamples | measure cookedvalue –Sum).Sum};
$sptstb = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;
$sptstb.DownloadFile('http://client.akamai.com/install/test-objects/10MB.bin', 'Out-Null');
Start-Job -Name sxrxs -scriptblock $sndrecsum -ArgumentList $Computer;
Get-Job -Name sxrxs | Wait-Job; $sndrecsumout = Get-Job -Name sxrxs | Receive-Job; ($sndrecsumout | measure -Maximum).Maximum
```

here's the issue. The output '($sndrecsumout | measure -Maximum).Maximum' should be getting the maximum value in the array $sndrecsumout. It does do that but the max value in the array is always wayyyy lower than it should be and never matches that shown in task manager/performance for 'Receive' and 'Send' (after conversion to the prevailing units shown in task manager/performance at the same time). So i'm not sure if task manager/performance is using performance counters or if i'm screwing up somewhere.

Anyway, two questions: First, how does task manager/performance get the values for 'Receive' and 'Send'? - and - Two, am I screwing up with the way i'm trying to do this?

Thanks for replies and advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ok, think i've got it figured out here, at least a little, maybe. This tracks with the Windows 10 performance monitor for the interface;

```
$sptst = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $Computer = hostname; $strlf += $("" | Out-String);
$totx = {
  get-counter -Counter '\Network Interface(Intel[R] Ethernet Connection [2] I218-V)\Bytes Total/sec' -MaxSamples 40 | ForEach {[math]::Round((($_.countersamples.cookedvalue | measure -sum).sum / 1Mb), 4)}
    };
  $recx = {
  get-counter -Counter '\network Interface(Intel[R] Ethernet Connection [2] I218-V)\Bytes Received/sec' -MaxSamples 40 | ForEach {[math]::Round((($_.countersamples.cookedvalue | measure -sum).sum / 1Mb), 4)}
    };
    $sntx = {
get-counter -Counter '\network Interface(Intel[R] Ethernet Connection [2] I218-V)\Bytes Sent/sec' -MaxSamples 40 | ForEach {[math]::Round((($_.countersamples.cookedvalue | measure -sum).sum / 1Mb), 4)}
    };

Start-Job -Name xtot -scriptblock $totx  -ArgumentList $Computer;
Start-Job -Name xrec -scriptblock $recx  -ArgumentList $Computer;
Start-Job -Name xsnt -scriptblock $sntx  -ArgumentList $Computer;

$ts = Measure-Command -Expression {$sptst.DownloadFile('http://testmy.net/dl-10MB', 'Out-Null')}; $dxtmex = [math]::Round($ts.TotalSeconds, 4);

Get-Job -Name xtot -HasMoreData $True | Wait-Job ; $outxtot = Get-Job -Name xtot | Receive-Job; 
$xthrx = ($outxtot | measure -Maximum).Maximum; $testnuma = $xthrx -match '^[\d\.]+$'; if ($testnuma -eq 'True') {$MBxthrx = $xthrx; $Mbpsxthrx = $xthrx / 0.125};

Get-Job -Name xrec -HasMoreData $True | Wait-Job; $outxrec = Get-Job -Name xrec | Receive-Job; 
$xrecx = ($outxrec | measure -Maximum).Maximum  ; $testnumb = $xrecx -match '^[\d\.]+$'; if ($testnumb -eq 'True') {$MBxrecx = $xrecx; $Mbpsxrecx = $xrecx / 0.125};

Get-Job -Name xsnt -HasMoreData $True | Wait-Job; $outxsnt = Get-Job -Name xsnt | Receive-Job; 
$xsntx = ($outxsnt | measure -Maximum).Maximum  ; $testnumb = $xsntx -match '^[\d\.]+$'; if ($testnumb -eq 'True') {$MBxsntx = $xsntx; $Mbpsxsntx = $xsntx / 0.125};

$txtl = '|Throughput = ' + $Mbpsxthrx + ' Mbps (' + $MBxthrx + ' MB/s) [ Test Time = ' + $dxtmex + ' seconds ]';

$rxsx = 'Received (D/L) : ' + $Mbpsxrecx + ' Mbps (' + $MBxrecx + ' MB/s)' + ' / Sent (U/L) : ' + $Mbpsxsntx + ' Mbps (' + $MBxsntx + ' MB/s)';

Return $txtl + $strlf + $rxsx
```

Edit: removed previous answer - this one is much better and improved. Ignore the labels 'Throughput' - 'Received (D/L)' - 'Sent (U/L)' as just called them something to differentiate while playing around with it so call them anything you wish if desired. 'Throughput' in the windows performance monitor is expressed as a percentage and not like this anyway but the results expressed in 'Throughput' above code when converted for percentage in math (not shown in above code) seem to track with the perf monitor which is why I chose the label 'Throughput' here. Also during this figured out how to get the correct instance name for the interface for use in the counters, I don't show its use (or the code for it) this post, and just put the interface name in above code, to keep strictly on topic but if someone wants to see it and its OK to do i'll post it here also. I'll just probably come back later and post it anyway if its Ok in this post and if not ya'll can remove it if you wish if it would be off topic some. Any improvements/suggestions welcome.

Thank You.